# Override CompareTo: What to do with null case?

Tags: c#, compareto

What should be returned in a `CompareTo` method when the given object is `null`?

The [MSDN Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shows a example where `1` is returned. But I would have expected to throw an error because comparing to `null` is not possible.

I expect different opinions to this answer. What could be a best practice approach?

Comment: What do you mean, comparing to null is "not possible"? All reference types can be compared to null normally. Otherwise you can wrap things with the [Nullable class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullable.aspx).

Comment: If you "expect different opinions" then this is not a fit for stack overflow as the FAQ clearly stats that you should `avoid asking subjective questions`.

Comment: the example is valid. As CompareTo returns the sort order of the objects, it is not unexpected to categorize null as the first element

Comment: Fyi, the currently accepted answer is not correct.

Comment: Thanks @jnm2 marked your answer as correct.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, there is a best practice. Contrary to what the other answers are saying, there is an expected standard, not just a most popular behavior.

The correct answer is given in the MSDN documentation for [`IComparable<T>.CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/43hc6wht.aspx) and [`IComparable.CompareTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto.aspx):

> By definition, any object compares greater than **null**, and two **null**
>   references compare equal to each other.

(Contractually, comparing greater is defined as: if `a > b` then `a.CompareTo(b) > 0`.)

This expected behavior is also borne out for example in [`Nullable.Compare<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxxt7t2a.aspx). Null always compares as less than a value.

It's also worth noting that for the non-generic compare, mismatching types should not be treated as null:

> The parameter, *obj*, must be the same type as the class or value type
>   that implements this interface; otherwise, an ArgumentException is
>   thrown.

This doesn't impact your question, but be aware, **[`Nullable<T> comparison operators`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx#sectionToggle4) (`==`, `!=`, `<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) do not follow the `IComparable` convention**.

> When you perform comparisons with nullable types, if the value of one
>   of the nullable types is null and the other is not, all comparisons
>   evaluate to `false` except for `!=` (not equal). It is important not to
>   assume that because a particular comparison returns `false`, the
>   opposite case returns `true`. In the following example, 10 is not
>   greater than, less than, nor equal to null. Only `num1 != num2`
>   evaluates to `true`.

There is also the odd result that `(int?)null == (int?)null` evaluates to true but `(int?)null <= (int?)null` does not.

Answer (score 2):

The choice is yours. It's not beyond the realm of possibility to imagine a valid use case where I'd compare something to nothing, and want "something" to be seen as greater.  But that's why you are overriding it, so you can decide how you want to handle that case.

Answer (score 1):

The best practise would depend on your particular case: comparing to `null` might be possible depending on the object you're comparing.

If I define my object such that `null` is the lowest possible value for any comparison, then comparing to `null` is clearly possible and has a well-defined result.  In other cases, throwing an exception might make more sense.

Ultimately, this is a (fairly subjective) design question, to which there's not necessarily one answer.

Answer (score 0):

CompareTo with null argument affects the case when sorting a list with null items. By returning 1 when the given object is null makes null appear on top of the list when sorted, which is the most popular behavior.

Comment: This isn't a complete answer, however everything it says is true so shouldn't have negative/zero score. It could be clearer `public int compareTo(MyType givenObject) { if (givenObject == null) { return 1; } else { ... }`